# how to return a value for a function in coffee-script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

I used coffee-script to write node.js, it works fine, what i want to know is  *how to return a value for a function in coffee-script*, here is my code

```
exports.find=->
    db.open((err, db)->
        unless err
            db.createCollection('test', (err, collection)-> 
                unless err
                    collection.find().toArray((err, items)->
                        unless err
                           //here how to return *items*
                            console.log(items)
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the DB related operations are all asynchronous, you should specify a callback function for the `find` routine.

(Sidenote:

you should use guard clauses like `return if err` instead of `unless err`. It decreases the indentation level and makes the code easier to read.

Or better yet, you should pass the error to the callback as the first parameter. This is the convention for node.js projects)

```
exports.find = (callback) ->
  db.open (err, db) ->
    return callback(err) if err
    db.createCollection 'test', (err, collection) ->
      return callback(err) if err
      collection.find().toArray (err, items) ->
        return callback(err) if err
        callback(null, items) // <<<================
```

Comment: qiao, how to use this method in another module? `db=require('./db'); items=db.find(???)`

Comment: @Veelian Just as how you use `db.open` in your example code. `db.find (err, items) -> doSomething(items)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use flow control such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) which let you to have cleaner code and easy to understand async flows

```
npm install async
```

---

```
async = require "async"

exports.find = (callback) ->
  async.waterfall [
    (callback) ->
      db.open (err, db) -> callback err, db

    (db, callback) ->
      db.createCollection 'test', (err, collection) -> callback err, collection

    (collection, callback) ->
      collection.find().toArray (err, items) -> callback err, items
  ], (err, items) ->
    if err then callback null else callback items
```

In this case, when error occurred `null` will be returned.

If there is no error, `items` will be returned